# Python _getch как в с++

Tags: c++, python, python-3.x, char, stdin

Как сделать функцию аналогичную _getch из с++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import termios, tty
def getch():
    def _getch():
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(fd)
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch
    return _getch()
```

Comment: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)